# link button on Master Page with Click Event on Content Page Stack-overflow Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I am trying to connect an asp link button on a master page to its click event on the content page. I followed descriptions from various online posts, but when I try running the page, I get a Stack-overflow exception in the get{} set{} part of the link button property. I could not find anyone else with this problem, mainly because I don't know what the actual problem is. Here are some bits of my code:

Master Page:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="mySite.master.cs" Inherits="mySite1.mySite" %>

<asp:LinkButton id="myLink" Text="Home" runat="server"/>
```

Master Page CS:

```
    public LinkButton myLink
    {
        get
        {
            return myLink; //FAILS HERE IF I COMMENT OUT THE SET.
        }
        set
        {
            myLink = value; //THIS IS WHERE IT FAILS!
        }
    }
```

Index.aspx.cs:

```
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(Master.myLink != null)
            Master.myLink.Click += new EventHandler(MainTabBtn_Click);
    }

    protected void MainTabBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
           //DO STUFF
     }
```

Index.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Title="MySite" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MySite.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Index.aspx.cs" Inherits="MySite1.Index" %>

<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/MySite.Master" %>
```

Anyone can tell from this what the problem is? Thanks for your help,

Marvin

Comment: Did you follow the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xxwa0ff0%28v=vs.140%29.aspx)?

Comment: @RickS: This documentation doesn't explain how to deal with a click event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assign a value to the myLink property which assigns it to the myLink property (`myLink = value`) which assigns it to the myLink property... in an infinite loop - the classic [stack overflow exception](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stackoverflowexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). [Find the control on the master page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xxwa0ff0%28v=vs.140%29.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   LinkButton myLink = (LinkButton)Master.FindControl("myLink");
   myLink.Click += new EventHandler(MainTabBtn_Click);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change

```
public LinkButton myLink
```

to

```
public LinkButton MyLink
```

Change the property name or the intern variable it is containing, any of those will be fine, because other way you will be calling the property `myLink`, that the value is `myLink`, that the value is `myLink`, etc etc