# Detect button press and pass value from Master Page before running Child Page

Tags: asp.net

Aim:

Detect which button is pressed on Master Page and get value into, for example, a session, before running Content Page.

Issue:

The content page runs before the master page

Thoughts:

This might be done by detecting which button is pressed?

I have two buttons on the master page and just need one value to be picked up.

Master Page Button Example:

```
 Protected Sub btnPrev_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

        Session.Item("questionbtn") = -1

    End Sub
```

Thoughts on trying to get the session from the content page in Page Load

```
  btnPrev.Click += New System.EventHandler(btnPrev)
```

I can't quite link it up and a bit stumped.

Reference:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xxwa0ff0(v=vs.140).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2

[link button on Master Page with Click Event on Content Page Stack-overflow Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30579906/link-button-on-master-page-with-click-event-on-content-page-stack-overflow-excep)

Comment: What do you mean by "content page runs before the master page"? This is not true at all. When on the content page you need info about which button was clicked?

Comment: When I click on the button  <asp:Button ID="btnPrev" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-prev" Text="Next" /> it runs the aspx.vb first then the master.vb page

Comment: All right, I will ask again - what do you mean by that? Page life cycle is just a series of events and their handlers, so I suspect you just see that Page_Load is .aspx.vb runs before button click handler in master (which is very normal). So, can you expand on your issue?

Comment: In nut shell that is the issue. Can the button (on the master page) value/name be detected on the .aspx.vb Page Load?

Comment: It is possible, yes. You can subscribe directly to button click in content page easily, and have different handlers for different buttons.

Comment: Could you explain how, was I close looking at btnPrev.Click += New System.EventHandler(btnPrev) ?

Comment: @Andrei still stumped, tried a few things and googled away. I'd appreciate any thoughs. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nearly... But I need the code to activate before the Content page still...

aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Test.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Testchild.aspx.vb" Inherits="Testchild" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">


</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">

      <asp:Label ID="lblFeedBack" runat="server" Text="test nothing happened"></asp:Label>
</asp:Content>
```

Master.VB

```
Partial Class Button
    Inherits System.Web.UI.MasterPage

    Protected Sub btnNext_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNext.Click

        Dim lblFeedBack As Label = DirectCast(ContentPlaceHolder1.FindControl("lblFeedBack"), Label)

        If lblFeedBack IsNot Nothing Then
            lblFeedBack.Text = "test worked next"

        End If

    End Sub

    Protected Sub btnPrev_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPrev.Click

        Dim lblFeedBack As Label = DirectCast(ContentPlaceHolder1.FindControl("lblFeedBack"), Label)

        If lblFeedBack IsNot Nothing Then
            lblFeedBack.Text = "test worked prev"

        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

.Master Page

```
<%@ Master Language="VB" CodeFile="Test.master.vb" Inherits="Button" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
       Start
         <p> </p>
          <asp:Button ID="btnPrev" runat="server" Text="Prev" style="width: 47px" /> 
          <asp:Button ID="btnNext" runat="server" Text="Next" style="width: 47px" /> 

         <p> </p>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        <p> </p>
        End here
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```